# Django 1.6 coverage data showing virtualenv items

Tags: python, django, code-coverage, coverage.py

I have a django 1.6 project which have minimal test coverage

when I run

`bash
coverage run manage.py test mainapp
coverage report --include=mainapp/*`

the output is

```
Name               Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------
mainapp/__init__       0      0   100%
mainapp/models        42     13    69%
mainapp/tests         20      0   100%
--------------------------------------
TOTAL                 62     13    79%
```

however this is very misleading since the coverage is nowehre near that, and it doesn't even include `views.py` file.

also if I just run `coverage report` it shows coverage for the `site-packages` directory in virtualenv created using `requirements.py` file,

the complete project is at https://github.com/vinu76jsr/librarymanagementsystem

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I need to add a `--setting` to the `manage.py`, in your case:

```
coverage run manage.py test --settings=librarymanagementsystem.settings mainapp
coverage report --include=mainapp/*
```

For the report command, `--include` is mandatory to avoid site-packages directory to be included in coverage.

If you use `South`, you should add `--omit="*migrations*"` too.

Comment: I am still getting the same result as before using what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To add a view in your coverage report, you need to test it! Add a `test_view.py` in your `mainapp` directory:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestCalls(TestCase):
    def test_call_view_denies_anonymous(self):
        response = self.client.get('/', follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/login/google/?next=%2F')
[...]
```

This will add your `urls.py` too:

```
$ coverage report --include=./*
Name                               Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------------------
librarymanagementsystem/__init__       0      0   100%
librarymanagementsystem/settings      34      0   100%
librarymanagementsystem/urls           6      0   100%
mainapp/__init__                       0      0   100%
mainapp/admin                         11      0   100%
mainapp/models                        42     13    69%
mainapp/test_view                      5      0   100%
mainapp/tests                         20      0   100%
mainapp/views                         61     35    43%
manage                                 6      0   100%
------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                186     48    74%
```

NB: You shouldn't use `unittest` directly, but `django.test` instead. [see doc (first warning)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests)